# How to assign page id with array in page_scheduled_event

Tags: php, functions

How to assign multiple unique page ids with the below code -

i have tried `'ID' => array('ID1, ID2, ID3),` but not worked.

```php
add_action( 'page_scheduled_event', 'publishhome' );
function publishhome() { 
    $time = current_time('mysql');
    $arg = array(
        'ID' => 16696, //here
        'post_date'     => $time,
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time ),
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    wp_update_post( $arg );
}
```

Comment: `wp_update_post()` does not support multiple post IDs. You'll need to call the function once for each the post IDs.

Comment: Sally is right, `wp_update_post` can't update multiple posts at the same time, you have to call it multiple times to update multiple posts

Comment: Is there any alternate to wp_update_post or any method to achieve.

Comment: @PuneetVerma, if by "alternate to wp_update_post" you meant a function that updates multiple posts at the same time, then no, there's no such function in WordPress core. But you could do something like so to update the posts from within the same function: `foreach ( array( 1, 2, 3 ) as $id ) { $arg = array( 'ID' => $id, ... ); wp_update_post( $arg ); }` And BTW, please tag/mention the person that you're replying to.